# Problem with autoloader in deploying php website to heroku

Tags: php, class, heroku, autoloader

I'm having trouble with my autoloader function working properly when my php code is deployed to heroku. I'm using namespaces.

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACjlQ.jpg)

[Heroku log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI5Wx.jpg)

It works correctly in localhost. I've already made the changes necessary for the paths to translate from localhost to heroku, since heroku uses /app as document root. Thus, in the case below, BASEURL is set to:

```
define('BASEURL', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

Here's part of the init file:

```
spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoaderPerson');

function myAutoLoaderPerson($className) {
    $path = BASEURL . '/classes/';      
    $extension = '.class.php';
    $fullPath = $path . $className . $extension;        

    require $fullPath;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])` is properly filled in?

I would rather recommend defining `BASEURL` using some relative definition, e.g., if the *Document Root* is two folder above the file defining `BASEURL`:

```
define('BASEURL', realpath(__DIR__ . "/../../"));
```

Or simplifying your autoloader, to make the path relative from it:

```
spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoaderPerson');

function myAutoLoaderPerson($className) {
    require_once __DIR__ . "/../../../classes/$className.class.php";
}
```

You suggested having `/app/classes/lib\foo.class.php` being returned.

Note the mix of `/` and `\`. Might be that the difference is that you are on [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) locally, but on [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) remotely.

If you follow the [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) convention, then it means your namespaces should match directories, but in order to do that, you probably need to transform `\` to `/`.

Maybe like this:

```
spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoaderPerson');

function myAutoLoaderPerson($className) {
    require_once __DIR__ . "/../<path..to>/classes/" . strtr($classname, "\\", "/") . ".class.php";
}
```

Comment: I'm trying it now, still can't get it to work. Anyway, if you compare the heroku log and the file structure pictures i posted above,* i think* that the paths are linking correctly. Namespaces should work the same in localhost and in heroku, right?

Comment: Still no dice. Every suggestion, when applied correctly just returns "/app/classes/lib\foo.class.php" on the logs, which should be the correct path. Could it be a problem with the namespace? HEELP, i wanna publish this, i wanna get a job ;)

Comment: Damn man, finally. Also, it makes sense. I wasn't aware of the windows - linux disparity. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out!!

Comment: Done. Still new to stack, one more thing i've learned i guess :)